# How use cmd command in c# program?

Tags: c#, 7zip

I want cmd command in my c# winforms program. I want use command to compress file with 7zip.

In normal cmd i use `cd "C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip" & 7z.exe a -tzip "C:\xyz\test\txt" "C:\xyz\test\txt" -m0=BZip2 -mx5`

```
string zip = @"/c C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip";
string file = @"/c C:\xyz\txt";
string conv = "/c & 7z.exe a -tzip";
string method = "/c -m0=BZip2 -mx5";

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
proc.Arguments = @"/c cd" + zip + conv + file + file + method;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
```

Doesn't work my code. How can i use this command in my program. I want compress file when i click in button

Comment: When you say that it doesnt work, what does it do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: Your current command line is `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c cd/c C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip/c & 7z.exe a -tzip/c C:\xyz\txt/c C:\xyz\txt/c -m0=BZip2 -mx5`. This almost certainly is not correct

Comment: i use simple command like ```string cmd = @"/c cd C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip"``` and not found this path

Comment: I will recommend using the 7zip sdk https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
// File (exe) to start: combination of folder and exe
string fileName = Path.Combine(
   // Let's not hardcode "C:\Program Files(x86)" and alike
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86),
  @"7-Zip", 
  @"7z.exe");

// If desired arguments are
// a -tzip "C:\xyz\test\txt" "C:\xyz\test\txt" -m0=BZip2 -mx5
// we can join them as 
string arguments = string.Join(" ",
  @"a",
  @"-tzip",                //TODO: you may want to have these values
  @"""C:\xyz\test\txt""",  // as variables like file, conv, method etc.
  @"""C:\xyz\test\txt""",
  @"-m0=BZip2",
  @"-mx5");

ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
  FileName  = fileName,   // We want to start fileName
  Arguments = arguments,  // With arguments
}

// Process is IDisposable, do not forget to Dispose HProcess handle
using (var process = Process.Start(procInfo)) {
  // It's fire and forget implementation, if you want to wait for results
  // add process.WaitForExit();
  // process.WaitForExit(); // uncomment, if you want to pause
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have made a mistake with your arguments.

Your current command line will be:

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c cd/c C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip/c & 7z.exe a -tzip/c C:\xyz\txt/c C:\xyz\txt/c -m0=BZip2 -mx5
```

The spurious `/c` everywhere is not going to help and neither are the lack of spaces.

I'm guessing what you meant to run was these two commands in succession:

```
cd C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip
7z.exe a -tzip C:\xyz\txt C:\xyz\txt -m0=BZip2 -mx5
```

Which means you should change your code to:

```
string zip = @" C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip";
string file = @" C:\xyz\txt";
string conv = " & 7z.exe a -tzip";
string method = " -m0=BZip2 -mx5";
```

This will produce:

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c cd C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip & 7z.exe a -tzip C:\xyz\txt C:\xyz\txt -m0=BZip2 -mx5
```